# Upload File MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

Ok.

I'm loosing my mind. I think understood how to upload files onto a server but I can not work it out.

I let the code, any ideas.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Cintas.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of iABC.Temp)" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderContenido" runat="server">
<%=Html.ValidationSummary("Se produjeron  errores al procesar la solicitud. Revise los errores e intente nuevamente.")%>

<% Using (Html.BeginForm("CargarArchivos", "ProcesosAutomaticos", FormMethod.Post, New With {.enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))%>
    <input type="file" name="abc" id="abc" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Button" />
<% End Using%>
</asp:Content>  



<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _  
Function CargarArchivos(ByVal abc As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult  
  ' But abc always is Nothing  
  ' Continue code  
End Function
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

The problem was I'm using MasterPages, so in the MasterPage I already have a tag **< form>**. I just add **enctype = "multipart/form-data"** to the main form and delete overload BeginForm from the secondary view

```
<% Using (Html.BeginForm("CargarArchivos", "ProcesosAutomaticos", New With {.enctype = "multipart/form-data"}, FormMethod.Post))%>
```

Thanks everybody. I hope this help someone else

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code into your View:

```
<div id="Componentsdiv">
@using (Html.BeginForm(<action>, <Controller>, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload TXT File</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>File</legend>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File1, "Select new file", new {  id="firstfile", type = "file"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File1)
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" hidden="hidden"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
</div>
```

Where File1 is a HttpPostedFileBase object.

Original Source on **snip2code**: [Upload File](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11298/Upload-File?fromPage=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your file input is called `abc` so the same should be your action argument:

```
Function CargarArchivos(ByVal abc As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult  
    If abc IsNot Nothing AndAlso abc.ContentLength > 0 Then
        abc.SaveAs("C:\" & "a.txt")  
    End If  
    Return View()  
End Function
```

Also you are using a wrong overload of the BeginForm method. It should be [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542.aspx):

```
<% Using (Html.BeginForm("CargarArchivos", "ProcesosAutomaticos", Nothing, FormMethod.Post, New With { .enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))%>
```

Notice how the arguments are inverted.

You might also checkout [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) from Phil Haack.

Comment: My mistake. Actually the argument name in Action is abc. That's because I'm trying many things. But abc always is Nothing

Comment: @Sebastián, please see my update about the wrong BeginForm method you are using. Make sure that the generated HTML is correct and your form has the correct enctype attribute. Don't confuse `routeValues` with `htmlAttributes` arguments.

Comment: Thanks for correction, I've changed BeginForm method. But I still get nothing in parameter. I don't know if it's necesary add something to the global.asax. I don't have any other idea